# apache camel spring boot restful webservice giving 404 error

Tags: spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

I was learning apache camel with spring boot. while trying to create A restful web service that returns a string after processing it, I received a 404 error in postman. here is the code I have used. I have tried to use /camel in the endpoint but no luck getting the same error again and again. event I tried to remove the starter web dependency and adding camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true in the application properties but I didn't get it worked.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BalanceRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .contextPath("/rest")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

        rest()
                .get("/balanceInquiry/{accountNumber}")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .produces("application/json")
                .to("direct:processRequest");

        from("direct:processRequest")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String accountNumber = exchange.getIn().getHeader("accountNumber", String.class);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("SOAP Response " + accountNumber);
                });
    }
}
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Esb-accounts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Esb-accounts</name>
    <description>Esb-accounts</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and here is my main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EsbAccountsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EsbAccountsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "/camel/*");
        registration.setName("CamelServlet");
        return registration;
    }

}
```

Comment: I reused all your source files to create a project and could not reproduce it, `curl http://localhost:8080/camel/balanceInquiry/10` gives `"SOAP Response 10"`